# order parameters in getopts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to write very simple script. It should take 2 args -h and -q. Both are optional, -h can be somewhere. So, -h -q should does the same action like -q -h. If I pass -a ,or -a -a -a - an error should occurs (I mean exit 1). If I pass -a -h -a -a -b.... - it should return "I couldn't recognize -a" + invoke help case. So -h has priority.
Could you help me?

```
while getopts "hq" OPTION
do
case $OPTION in
  h)
     echo "Help here!" ;
     exit 0;
     
esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

while getopts "hq" OPTION
do
case $OPTION in
  q) #quiet - return 0, do nothing. 
     exit 0;;
 

                   
  *) #If -a or sth
     echo "I couldn't recognize args" 
     echo "Help here" 
     exit 1
     ;;
     
esac
     
done
```

Comment: You need to use a single `while getopts` loop to process *all* of the options, not one for `-h` followed by one for `-q`.

Comment: I found this trick with 2 loops on stack..

Comment: Where on stack? It should probably corrected, because it will not work right (unless there's some weird situation where makes sense).

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts :hq OPTION
do  
    case $OPTION in
    h) echo "Help here!" ;
       exit 0;;
    q) echo "quiet do nothing."
       exit 0;;
    ?) echo "I couldn't recognize option [$1]" 
       exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Note `:hq` and `?)` to process incorrect options (-a -b ...)

Comment: You could explain, regarding SO question:  *`while getopts` will **loop** over each option passed to script*...